# Unzip file using PHP that was zipped and uploaded using Java Android

Tags: java, php, android, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file that was zipped and uploaded using Java Android. Unluckily, I was not able to unzip it. Is there an issue there? I have tried searching through Google and this forum how to unzip files and there were a lot of answers but when I tried them, it's not working on mine.

Scenario:

a. Click a button in Android app to zip all CSV files. Then upload the zipped file. (I am currently using WAMP localhost).

b. Unzip the uploaded file.

c. Insert data to the table.

Currently, with the code that I have, I am able to zip and upload the file. Problem arises during the unzipping. I cannot unzip the file.

Current code:

```
//Upload the file
$file_path = "ZipFiles/";     
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}


//Unzip the uploaded file
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('myUpload.zip');
$zip->extractTo('UnzipFiles/');
$zip->close();
```

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: I am only showing logs during the zipping and uploading. When I unzip the file, I am not telling that to the user of the app

Comment: there is no default way to zip files in Android, so you need to know how exactly it was zipped (zipping source code)

Comment: I do have a code in Java doing the zipping part

Comment: I am encountering problem in unzipping using php, that is why i posted the unzipping part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somebody will encounter this problem, that is why I'll be posting the workaround that I have found. Thanks to this [site](http://snipplr.com/view/69947/script-for-uploading-zip-file-and-unzip-it-on-the-server/), I successfully unzip the file.

```
//Upload the file
$file_path = "ZipFiles/";     
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($file_path);
    $zip->extractTo("UnzipFiles/");
    $zip->close(); 
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```